# 2 App connecting to same Parse account

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications, push, devicetoken

I have single code base for 2 different apps and we change the applicationID in gradle to build as two different apps. These both connect to same parse account. When I check _Installation class deviceToken & PushType is not updating.

Let me know if anyone came across same issue.

Comment: why are you using 2 android app for the same Parse account? I'm not sure if I understood well your question...

Comment: We are building app like consumer and merchant which speaks to same parse backend. But requirement is we need to install both the app in same device.